# Errors when trying to connect to a database using VBA in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to connect to a database using VBA in excel but don't know what is wrong. Any suggestions?

Here is the code. I want to get the query results and put then into an excel sheet at the same time

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim dd As String
Dim nn As String

OMCS_Connection.Show

If OMCS_Connection.CommandButton1 = False Then

dd = OMCS_Connection.TextBoxa.Value
nn = OMCS_Connection.TextBoxb.Value
End If

Dim order_number As String
order_number = TextBox1.Text
Dim sql_query As String

Set ad = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")      'create and open ODBC connection
ad.ConnectionString = "ODBC;DRIVER=IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1; DSN=ODRPTDB;UID = " & dd & " ; PWD = " & nn & ";"
'UID=me"
ad.Open

sql_query = "SELECT" & _
                "CMOT.MFGNO AS MANUFACTURING_NUMBER," & _
                "'BOX' AS ORDER_TYPE," & _
                "CMOT.IDCUS AS CUSTOMER_ID," & _
                "CMOT.WTCTN AS WT_CUSTOMER_ID," & _
                "CMOT.PLORN AS ORDER_NUMBER," & _
                "CMOT.IDMAC AS MACHINE_TYPE," & _
                "CMOT.IDSMN AS MODEL_NUMBER," & _
                "'    ' AS NEW_MACHINE_TYPE," & _
                "'    ' AS NEW_MODEL_NUMBER," & _
                "CMOT.BOXSH AS PSSD," & _
                "CMOT.ALDPF AS RSSD," & _
                "COGUS.ITPDC AS REGION" & _
                "FROM DB2COATG.COS1S0T0 CMOT" & _
                "INNER JOIN COGUS.WTCTN_CONVERSION COGUS" & _
                "ON(COGUS.WTCTN = CMOT.WTCTN AND COGUS.REGIO = CMOT.REGIO)" & _
                "WHERE CMOT.PLORN IN  (" & order_number & ");"


Set RS = ad.Execute(sql_query)        'execute query
```

Comment: Hi, may I know what's the error message ?

Comment: Hi Larry, here is the error I got:
SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "127.0.0.1".  Communication function detecting the error: "selectForConnectTimeout".  Protocol specific error code(s): "0", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001

Answer (score 0):

Before ad.open try inserting the following line
`ad.CommandTimeout=0`
This should prevent the query from timing out if it runs long.
If that does not work, it would help to know what line of code is throwing the error. Do you know how to step thought the code?

Comment: Thank you so much, I just used another code and it worked fine.